# Cucumber refuses to run tests in a random order

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

I have a decently sized cucumber test suite, but they currently all run in defined order. I want to run them in a random order. The cucumber docs say that I should be able to run `cucumber -P --order random` and have the tests be shuffled before execution. I have witnessed this as not happening. In fact, the presence (or lack) of the --order flag seems to do nothing.

What could be stopping my suite from running in a random order? I'm not running with a profile (hence the -P) so nothing should be already defined.

Comment: What's your version of cucumber and cucumber-core? Can you also share a link of the docs where you found this. You shouldn't need the -P anyway. As per https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/485e67dc385c84ceb596a17898c06b0c2bb9bd9e/History.md, it seems the randomize feature only became stable in the latest versions, so worth checking that.

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) code that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: cucumber is 2.3.3 and cucumber-core is 1.4.0 which are (afaict) the latest. The options show up in `cucumber --help` so it would be a jerk move to have them and for them to not be implemented yet, anyway. :)

Comment: I don't think anybody provides free tools to be a jerk. There isn't enough information to reproduce the issue. Can you add more info such as the code as @orde suggested, the environment (OS, ruby ver, etc.)?

Comment: The jerk thing was tongue-in-cheek. I know no one's actually being a jerk here. Ruby is 2.3.1, OS is OSX 10.11.5, Rails 4.2, cucumber 2.2.3, cucumber-core 1.4.0. The goalposts seem to have changed now, though. With a basically standard config file, feature files aren't shuffled but the order of the features inside them are. That is `A.feature` always runs before `B.feature`, but `A`'s scenarios don't always run in defined order.

Answer (score 0):

This is part from the help of cucumber:

```
--order TYPE[:SEED]          Run examples in the specified order. Available types:
                                       [defined]     Run scenarios in the order they were defined (default).
                                       [random]      Shuffle scenarios before running.
                                     Specify SEED to reproduce the shuffling from a previous run.
                                       e.g. --order random:5738
```

My opinion is you might try adding a seed number.

Comment: Hi @Gu Yu, welcome to SO. I have edited your answer for now. In future please format your questions and and answers as per [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).